# Differences between evil-normal-state-map and evil-motion-state-map

Tags: key-bindings, evil, keymap

Documentation for `evil-normal-state-map`:

> Keymap for Normal state.

Documentation for `evil-motion-state-map`:

> Keymap for Motion state.

Does Vim have a so-called "motion mode"? In Vim, executing `:help Normal-mode` would give you the documentation on Vim modes, while `:help Motion-mode` tells me `E149: Sorry, no help for Motion-mode`.

Also, when mapping keys in evil-state, which statement should I use?

- `(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd <key>) <command>)`
- `(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd <key>) <command>)`

I'm using Spacemace, in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Motion state is an Evil-specific thing, intended for modes where you don't edit text, but still want Vim-style movement available, with all other keys of that mode passing through.  Help buffers are an example of such a case, the package.el listing is another one.

Typically you want commands moving point in `evil-motion-state-map` and everything else in `evil-normal-state-map`.  As Evil is set up to look up keys in `evil-normal-state-map` first, then in `evil-motion-state-map`, movements will be available in normal state as well.